# How to print an element from an array which is inside the hash in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print the outputs from an API which are in multidimensional format.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $content={
  'school_set' => 'SSET1234',
  'result' => [
    {
      'school_name' => 'school_abc',
      'display_value' => 'IL25',
      'school_link' => 'example.com',
      'status' => 'registerd',
      'status_message' => 'only arts',
      'school_id' => '58c388d40596191f',
    }
  ],
  'school_table' => 'arts_schools'
};

print "school_name is=".$content{result}[0]{school_name};
print "school_status is=".$content{result}[3]{status};
```

```
output
Global symbol "%content" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %content"?) at test8.pl line 20.
Global symbol "%content" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %content"?) at test8.pl line 21.
```

I have to print the outputs like below from the result.

```
school_name = school_abc
school_status = registered
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which defines and fills such a hash and outputs one of the other, simpler parts - or at least fails to output the part in question. Describe how it fails, e.g. quote the error you get.

Comment: I think you are missing one level, because it is a hash in an array in a hash. Did you try something like `$content{result}[0]{school_name}`?

Comment: That looks like JSON, not Perl. Did you forget to mention that you decoded a JSON input, and put it into a variable called `$content`? Also, Yunnosch is correct, you want a `[0]` in between to make it work.

Comment: @Yunnosch He probably gets output `school_name is=school_status is=`, because he has not enabled warnings, and no newline in print.

Comment: Would you mind setting up your MRE-hash like `my %content=(...);`? (`%`!=`$` and `()` != `{}`) I ask because I suspect that your problems come from the setup and not from the accesses....

Comment: @Yunnosch If you ask him to create a definition for the hash, he is going to make up something that has nothing to do with his actual problem. He says the data comes from an API. If you want to see the data structure, ask him to print it with Data::Dumper.

Comment: @TLP I assume that is what they did and I worry they missed the difference between the data dumper output and the code for recreating it. I.e. I want them to make sure that what they show is a MRE, i.e. that it at least gets the same symptoms. Also by that I want to get the clarification needed to decide between the two paths in the answer by choroba. Which I belatedly realised is exactly what I found out....

Comment: @Yunnosch I expect what we saw in the first version of this question was a data dump from the API, which to me suggests JSON. It's really difficult to guess when they don't answer questions, and don't know how to give relevant info.

Answer (score 2):

If `$content` is a hash reference, you need to dereference it first. Use the arrow operator for that:

```
$content->{result}[0]{school_name}
```

The syntax without the arrow is only possible for `%content`.

```
my %content = ( result => [ { school_name => 'abc' } ] );
print $content{result}[0]{school_name};
```

If you want to print all the results, you have to loop over the array somehow. For example

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $content = {
    'result' => [
        {
            'school_name' => 'school_abc',
            'status' => 'registerd',
        },
        {
            'school_name' => 'school_def',
            'status' => 'pending',
        }
    ],
};

for my $school (@{ $content->{result} }) {
    print "school_name is $school->{school_name}, status is $school->{status}\n";

}
```

Comment: I got this
Not a HASH reference at test8.pl line 20.

Comment: @RasheedMohammed: Updated with the array in between.

Comment: thanks @choroba, what if I don't know the index ?

Comment: @RasheedMohammed: And what output do you expect? All of the existing values for the key?

Comment: yes, I just have to print the key names and the values.

Comment: Updated. `@{ ... }` shows how to dereference a whole array reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure assumes an array, perhaps it would be useful to utilize loop output for the data of interest.

The data presented as hash reference and will require de-referencing to loop through an array.

Following code snippet is based on your posted code and demonstrates how desired output can be achieved.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dataset = {
              'school_set' => 'SSET1234',
              'result' => [
                {
                  'school_name' => 'school_abc',
                  'display_value' => 'IL25',
                  'school_link' => 'example.com',
                  'status' => 'registerd',
                  'status_message' => 'only arts',
                  'school_id' => '58c388d40596191f',
                }
              ],
              'school_table' => 'arts_schools'
            };

for my $item ( @{$dataset->{result}} ) {
    say "school_name is   = $item->{school_name}\n"
      . "school_status is = $item->{status}";
}

exit 0;
```

Output

```
school_name is   = school_abc
school_status is = registerd
```

Comment: what if I don't know the elment name on before hand ? can I just say something like this ?  say "$key$i= value of $i";

Comment: You need do some reading on Perl programming - for example [Modern Perl](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/modern-perl-fourth-edition_p1_0.pdf). You can loop over a hash by utilizing keys `for my $key ( sort keys %hash ) { ... }`, or if you use array you can loop over all elements by `for my $elem ( @array ) { ... }`. Use Google to look for __Perl bookshelf__ although it would be old books but still you can learn a lot from them.